# TortoiseSVN trunk checkout "Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS" error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, http-status-code-403

My problem is that every time I do some operation with an URL like the following one: https://nttt.dttt.com:8443/svn/nttt/Med/trunk I get

> Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS".

The user and password I supplied was correct, so no problem there.

I don't know where the problem lies, I don't know if it is the server(on witch I don't have any control) or my Tortoise client.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Superfilin and Dave Markle were right, it was a server configuration problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it is TroitoiseSVN. The problem most likely is that you don't have access to full tree or all HTTP operations. Try accessing these URLs in your browser:

https://nttt.dttt.com:8443/svn/nttt

https://nttt.dttt.com:8443/svn/nttt/Med

https://nttt.dttt.com:8443/svn/nttt/Med/trunk

And see if you get any 403 errors. Otherwise you will need to talk to your system administrator to fix the rights.

Comment: In the browser I get the same error, and I don't have a Proxy...So are you saying that that the problem is my internet connection, or some kind of firewall issue?

Comment: It's most likely the configuration of your server.

Comment: @S Bogdan, I agree to Dave, it's your server configuration.

Comment: I just got the same error : I had simply forgotten to add my svn user to my svn "developpers" group (using VisualSVN Server)

Comment: I have same problem like cosmo0, mistyping wrong group name. So please check access.conf file

Answer (score 3):

This error can happen if you checkout a SVN repository with a different account. The account data is stored to disk, and the next time you want to commit to a repository SVN may use the wrong account. It could help to specify the right account in the console or terminal:

```
svn commit -m "my message" --username my_username --password my_password
```

Comment: I had similar issue , i was trying to checkout age old code from my svn base, just supplying username and password let me access the code. thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 2):

according to this post it is a known bug http://groups.google.com/group/visualsvn/browse_thread/thread/e16fe2e3c5fdab8d?pli=1
Setting username and password manually may help

Comment: I already looked at that discussion, but I don't know how to set the username and password manually

Comment: something like this in command line: svn update --username asdf --password asdf, but i never tried it through command line

Answer (score 2):

You just need to delete the saved data from your SVN. Go to this path All Programs --> TSVN --> settings -->Saved Data ---> Clear the Authentication Data. After doing this, you can access to your SVN path with the proper credentials.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you're using the wrong URL.  It's also possible that your apache server is misconfigured.

What happens when you put that URL into your web browser?  Can you see it?  Try verifying the path first by testing your URL with the browser, then try Tortoise again.

Comment: The URL is fine, and when I try it in the browser I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

i was also debugging this issue. I have a control over the server. So just found out that the group "everyone", if present, was configured to "No Access" (which I did it) and it was conflicting with my admin rights so just removed it completely to resolve this forbidden user error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it updating TortoiseSVN to last version avaliable (1.8.10 at the moment).

I used to run 1.6.x.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message just now when trying to update my working copy.

As I knew which directory needed to be updated, I tried to update just that and it worked (Strangely enough).

After that, it seems the issue is gone for the moment. I really do not understand what was going on.

To recap: I was trying to update a repository having its root at

```
    https://MyServer/repos/config/MyProject/trunk
```

and it was complaining

```
    svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response
    to OPTIONS request for 'https://MyServer/repos/config'
```

I did then an

```
    cd $WORKINGCOPY/path/to/my/changed/dir
    svn up ... https://MyServer/repos/config/path/to/my/changed/dir/ .
```

and this worked.

Any following svn up now works.

Answer (score 0):

that 403 comes in response if you don't have permissions on the repository to Read/Write you may only have Read permissions and you're trying to commit changes so you're not allowed 
well in this case you need to consult with your system administrator to allow you proper privileges and permissions according to you role

and 
I don't know if it is the server(on which I don't have any control) or my Tortoise client.

your client is just fine only server permissions needs a consideration

Answer (score 0):

What if this problem appears only for big amount of files. The commit works normally for one single folder, or a folder including some files, but when it's a big hierarchy, the process starts and stops with the error message just before completing the commit.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same error message. After checking, I realized that I was using a bad project name in the URL. Might be worth checking your URL too.